Named client filters in Micronaut framework
I have a micronaut service which has two filters with @Named annotation set to unique values. Without @Named annotation on HttpClient, filters work fine. But, with @Named annotation, it does not work. In simple @ClientFilters class definition is applied to all the client requests globally.
Requirement is to have multiple ClientFilters classes and each HttpClient injection should be associated to only specific filter definition.
Note: URL Pattern matching is one option for each filter, but in this case URL pattern is not known or dynamic.
Thanks
So far, I tried this and filter class is not getting applied when I use @Named annotation in HttpClient class as shown in below code snippets
@ClientFilter(Filter.MATCH_ALL_PATTERN)
@Named("MyHttpClient1")
public class ClientInterceptor1 {

    
    @RequestFilter
    @ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.BLOCKING)
    public void filterRequest(MutableHttpRequest<?> request) {
      // some logic    
    }
}

@ClientFilter(Filter.MATCH_ALL_PATTERN)
@Named("MyHttpClient2")
public class ClientInterceptor2 {

    
    @RequestFilter
    @ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.BLOCKING)
    public void filterRequest(MutableHttpRequest<?> request) {
      // some logic    
    }
}

Bean to provide the HttpClient Configuration
@Factory
public class HttpClientFactory {
    @Bean
    @Named("MyHttpClient1")
    public HttpClient myLocalhttpClient(HttpClientConfiguration httpClientConfiguration) throws   MalformedURLException {
        return HttpClient.create(new URL("http://localhost"), httpClientConfiguration);
    }
}

And a service class
@Controller("/test")
@RequestScope
public class TestResource {

    @Inject
    @Named("MyHttpClient1")
    HttpClient httpClient;

    @Get(uri = "/http")
    public HttpResponse<?> testHttpClient() {
        ...
        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.toBlocking().exchange(request, String.class);
        ...
        return HttpResponse.ok();
    }
}

